# First SQL result is returned twice

Tags: php, sql

For reasons I have yet to understand, first row of a query is returned twice. I also added screenshot comparison of the exact same SQL on my page and in phpmyadmin:

[image: Example output]
Here is the code:

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT a.id, a.title, a.content, a.posted, a.author, u.login FROM articles a INNER JOIN users u ON a.author=u.id ORDER BY a.id DESC"))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$content,$posted,$author,$login);             
    $stmt->store_result();
    echo "numrows".$stmt->num_rows();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        $data[] = array(
                   'id'    => $id,
                   'title'     => $title,
                   'content'     => $content,  
                   'posted'     => $posted,
                   'author'     => $author,
                   'login'     => $login                       
        );
        foreach($data as $row) 
        {
            echo '<span>'.$row['title'] . '</span>';
            echo '<span>'.$row['posted'].' | '.$row['login'].'</span><br /><br />';
            echo $row['content'] . '<br /><br />';
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Go through the steps with pen and paper. You keep appending rows to `$data`, and each time you do, you also loop over all rows already in `$data`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please take foreach out of while loop?

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        $data[] = array(
                   'id'    => $id,
                   'title'     => $title,
                   'content'     => $content,  
                   'posted'     => $posted,
                   'author'     => $author,
                   'login'     => $login                       
        );

    }

foreach($data as $row) 
        {
            echo '<span>'.$row['title'] . '</span>';
            echo '<span>'.$row['posted'].' | '.$row['login'].'</span><br /><br />';
            echo $row['content'] . '<br /><br />';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one:

if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT a.id, a.title, a.content, a.posted, a.author, u.login FROM articles a INNER JOIN users u ON a.author=u.id ORDER BY a.id DESC"))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$content,$posted,$author,$login);             
    $stmt->store_result();
    echo "numrows".$stmt->num_rows();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        $data[] = array(
                   'id'    => $id,
                   'title'     => $title,
                   'content'     => $content,  
                   'posted'     => $posted,
                   'author'     => $author,
                   'login'     => $login                       
        );
        foreach($data as $row) 
        {
            echo '<span>'.$row['title'] . '</span>';
            echo '<span>'.$row['posted'].' | '.$row['login'].'</span><br /><br />';
            echo $row['content'] . '<br /><br />';
        }
        $data = []; 
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```